# Can I use score and metric interchangeabily?

Tags: meaning

What is the different between scores and metrics? If I have a table to store engagement metrics, like the level of the engagement, can I call it engagement scores?

Another example would be another table called reading scores, that stores things like adverb count or word count. Can I call it reading metrics?

Comment: We need more context

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. I am afraid your question is not very clear, and it might receive better answers on a SE site about the field in which these terms are used.

Comment: As pointed out above, this question seems too vague, you should edit it and expand it, providing more information.

Comment: MW: a standard of measurement;
no metric exists that can be applied directly to happiness
— Scientific Monthly